# Power tower convergence outside of convergence bounds, where did I go wrong?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

It is said a power tower

$$x^{x^{x^{x^{x^ \cdots}}}}$$

converges iff $ e^{-e} \lt x \lt e^{\frac{1}{e}}$

Is the following incorrect?

Assume $$x^{x^{x^{x^{x^ \cdots}}}} = \frac{1}{1000000}$$
Then we can say
$$x^{\frac{1}{1000000}} = \frac{1}{1000000}$$
$$\ln{ x^{\frac{1}{1000000}}} = \ln{ \frac{1}{1000000}}$$
$$\frac{1}{1000000} \ln{x} = \ln{ \frac{1}{1000000}}$$
$$\ln{x} = 1000000 \ln{ \frac{1}{1000000}}$$
$$ x = e^{1000000 \ln{ \frac{1}{1000000}}}$$
Here, $x$ is less than our bound of $ e^{-e}$

Comment: I think maybe you are wrong in your original assumption that the power tower can equal that value.

Answer (score 2):

> Notice, for the 'Product Log Function' (or the Lambert $\text{W}$-function) is defined as follows:
>
> $$f(z)=ze^z\to z=f^{-1}(ze^z)=\text{W}(ze^z)\tag1$$

---

Now, we know that for $k\in\mathbb{R}^+$ (real, and bigger than zero) $\ln(k)$ is well defined.

Now, your question is about:

$$y(k)=k^{k^{k^{k^{\dots}}}}=-\frac{\text{W}\left(-\ln(k)\right)}{\ln(k)}\tag2$$

Eisenstein's (1844) considered this series of the infinite [power tower](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html). $y(k)$ converges iff $e^{-e}\le k\le e^{\frac{1}{e}}$; OEIS [A073230](http://oeis.org/A073230) and [A073229](http://oeis.org/A073229)), as shown by Euler (1783) and Eisenstein (1844) (Le Lionnais 1983; Wells 1986, p. 35).